# SwiftUI ShareLink sheet does not have save to album option

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wwdc

Using SwiftUI's new `ShareLink`, with a photo. The Share sheet does not have save to album option. Does anyone know how could I get that option, because I need to save an image to the photo library.

As you can see on the screenshot below, it only has add to shared album option.

```
struct Photo: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        ProxyRepresentation(\.image)
    }

    public var image: Image
    public var caption: String
}

ShareLink(item: photo, preview: SharePreview(photo.caption, image: Image("miniIcon"))) { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Solved. For whoever encountered this problem. You need to add photo library permission in the Info plist.

Comment: The key to add to your Info.plist is `Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description` and the value is the text that the user will see in the permissions prompt.